# What's the relationship between the actor's pose and shape's pose in PhysX?

Tags: directx12, physx, directxmath

I have 2 Meshes and I want to add physics to them. The first is a primitive box, the second is a terrain.

The box and terrain are made with DirectXMath

Using the PhysX library, I made a copy of the terrain and used it to create a Triangle mesh, and I created a box using `physx::PxBoxGeometry`  as you can see here:

```
        physx::PxTransform boxPos(physx::PxVec3(0.0f, 20, 0.0f));
        physx::PxBoxGeometry boxGeometry(physx::PxVec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
        physx::PxShape* shape =m_pPhysics->createShape(boxGeometry, *m_pMaterial);
        physx::PxRigidDynamic* boxRigid = m_pPhysics->createRigidDynamic(boxPos);
        boxRigid->attachShape(*shape);
        physx::PxRigidBodyExt::updateMassAndInertia(*boxRigid, .15f);
                    
        m_pScene->addActor(*boxRigid);
        m_pPhysicsActors.push_back(boxRigid);
```

I added them to the scene and I ran the simulation and I can see the box is dropped and  flipped couple times using Physx Visual Debugger (though, on some runs the debugger shows artifacts, anyway)

I found out that I can get the translation and rotation by using `m_pPhysicsActors[]->getGlobalPose()` which is both quaternion for rotation and vector for position so I thought that's it

But in the hello world snippets they made this function:

```
/**
\brief Retrieves the world space pose of the shape.

\param[in] shape The shape for which to get the global pose.
\param[in] actor The actor to which the shape is attached

\return Global pose of shape.
*/
static PX_INLINE    PxTransform     getGlobalPose(const PxShape& shape, const PxRigidActor& actor)
{
    return actor.getGlobalPose() * shape.getLocalPose();
}
```

then they put the output in a matrix

Now I am confused, why multiply `actor.getGlobalPose() * shape.getLocalPose();`?

I thought the shape and the actor are the same thing, like a relationship or a property. Since I assign a shape to an actor, I imagine that if I rotate a shape, I rotate the actor vice versa as it is one thing.

This is where I am lost! Can someone walk me through how to update render items from PhysX?

Comment: This looks like a very conventional transformation hierarchy, with shapes attached relative to an actor, and an actor able to move around the world. This lets you do things like attach multiple shapes to an actor, then move and rotate them as an ensemble by moving the actor - rather than needing to update every contained shape's position and rotation one by one. Where are you running into difficulty using the code that you found from the hello world snippet?

Comment: I can see your point, if I understood you correctly you mean something like a car's body and its 4 wheels, I am trying to understand the difference between actor.getGlobalPose() and shape.getLocalPose()
so since an actor can have multiple shapes, the actor.getGlobalPose() is like the position & rotation of the centre of the actor in world space and the  shape.getLocalPose() is like the local space for each shape in the actor, so we need to multiply them to get the world space of each shape, right? another question if one shape represent an actor , does this mean that they are interchangeable?

Comment: Sounds like you've figured things out. Be sure to post an Answer below explaining your current understanding. To answer your second question: a local position will never be interchangeable with a world position. Knowing that "the car body shape is centered on the car (local position (0,0,0))" does not tell you where the car is in the city, even if the car body is the only shape that makes up the car.

Comment: @DMGregory  I understand that the local position cant be used this way, I meant if one actor have one shape then we can get the shape position by using actor.getGlobalPose().

Comment: I mean to get the world position of a shape

Comment: If the shape is at the actor origin. But if the shape is not at the origin (think of a pendulum where the weight is a distance away from the pivot) then you'll need to take into account the shape's local position and its parent object's rotation.

Answer (score 1):

As **DMGregory** mentioned

An actor can have many shapes(parts), all together ensembles the overall actor's behaviour, thus each shape can have it's own position(in local space) relative to the actor's position(in world space).

Even if one actor has one shape, the shape may not always be at the centre of the actor

> think of a pendulum where the weight is a distance away from the pivot

Thus, we still need to use the shape's world pose instead of the actor pose.

so we will still need this conversion `actor.getGlobalPose() * shape.getLocalPose();` to get the shape's world pose